# C# dll to solve simple equation

Tags: c#, dll, equation, solver

I am looking for a C# dll to solve simple equation. Example ..

```
10 = 2 + 3 + x
```

Result should be x = 5;

Is there a free DLL?

Comment: um why doesn't int x = 10 - 3 -2; work?

Comment: @Conrad Frix: I think OP is looking for a DLL that will solve for `x` given the equation as a string.

Comment: Wolfram.Mathematica.Algebra.ChangeSubject("10 = 2 + 3 + x", "x")

Comment: Sure, if you write it and put it on CodePlex. ;)

Comment: @ Conrad Frix - ter can be many () and many other operators and x can be at multiple places

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used this Math Expression Parsing library with positive results.  The documentation he's provided was very useful to boot.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MathieuMathParser.aspx?display=Print

Your app can then accommodate ad hoc equations which the library will parse into component parts.  You can then provide the values for required variables and it will evaluate the result.

The library includes many function (trig, log, factorials, datetime, random, etc.) and can handle user-defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Math Expression Editor Light (MEEL)](http://othercontrols.com/en/products/mathexpressioneditorlight/)

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliation any time you promote your own product, project, or site.  Please read the relevant section of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for details.

Answer (score -3):

Use System.Math if you have to make something more diffucult then an addition. Otherwise .. do it your self IT'S FREE !

Comment: It's only free if your time is worthless (unless you want to learn how to evaluate expressions, in which case it's a good investment)

Comment: @ Jason - this is not the direction that we will be taking ... i need this for Demo purposes only