# Dynamically solving equations

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# app in which I need to dynamically solve equations. For example, I have the following at this time:

```
decimal[] v1s = GetV1Values();
decimal[] v2s = GetV2Values();

if (v1s.Length != v2s.Length) 
{
  throw new Exception();
}

string[] equations = new string[] {
  "$V1 + $V2",
  "$V1 * 3 - $V2",
  "$V1 - $V2"
};

foreach (var equation in equations)
{
  for (var i=0; i<v1s.Length; i++)
  {
    var op1 = v1s[i];
    var op2 = v2s[i];

    var result = ?  // I'm not sure how to plug op1 and op2 into equation
    Console.WriteLine(equation + " = " + result;
  }
}
```

How do I take values from my value arrays and plug them into an `equation` and get a result? I'm open to tackling this problem using a different approach in C#. I'm just not sure how to evaluate equations in C#.

Comment: Your question seems to be about dynamically evaluating expressions, not solving equations (which is significantly more complicated...). Your "equations" are not equations because they do not equate to anything, e.g. `y = 2x + 3, 2y = -5x - 8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# dll to solve simple equation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268531/c-sharp-dll-to-solve-simple-equation)

Comment: If you want to dynamically evaluate expressions, see here: http://flee.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon can do this by using Delegates array. Instead of storing your equations as an array of strings, you can store method calls.
Something like

```
Func<int>[] equations = { eqn1, eqn2, eqn3 };  
foreach (var equation in equations)
{
  for (var i=0; i<v1s.Length; i++)
  {
    var op1 = v1s[i];
    var op2 = v2s[i];

    var result = equation(op1, op2);
    Console.WriteLine(equation + " = " + result;
  }
} 

public static int eqn1 (int v1, int v2)  
{  
  return v1 + v2;  
}  
public static int eqn2 (int v1, int v2)  
{   
  return v1 * 3 - v2;  
}  
public static int eqn3 (int v1, int v2)  
{   
  return v1 - v2;  
}
```

**Update:**
Here's working example:

```
public delegate decimal Eqn(decimal v1, decimal v2);
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  decimal[] v1s = {4, 5, 6}; //GetV1Values();
  decimal[] v2s = {2, 3, 4}; //GetV2Values();

  Eqn[] equations = { eqn1, eqn2, eqn3 };  
  foreach (var equation in equations)
  {
    for (var i=0; i<v1s.Length; i++)
    {
      var op1 = v1s[i];
      var op2 = v2s[i];

      var result = equation(op1, op2);
      Console.WriteLine("Result = " + result);
    }
  } 
}
public static decimal eqn1 (decimal v1, decimal v2)  
{  
  return v1 + v2;  
}  
public static decimal eqn2 (decimal v1, decimal v2)  
{   
  return v1 * 3 - v2;  
}  
public static decimal eqn3 (decimal v1, decimal v2)  
{   
  return v1 - v2;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you go down the lane of evaluating an expression, you have to know

1. What is the grammar a.k.a syntax for the expression?
2. Do you need to use c# to evaluate the expression?
3. How frequently in your app do you need to evaluate an expression? Are there performance considerations?
4. Will your expressions support functions?

I can't help you without knowing some context. I will make some broad assumptions and throw some ideas which might help you.

1. You can let the caller provide the expression in c#. You can the auto generate a simple c# app which evaluates that expression. And your function will simply spawn a process with args  to  evaluate the expression
2. Instead of c#, you can use a dynamic language like perl, if you have that option. A simple eval block on perl can do the evaluation of dynamic code block.
3. If you want to do this in an efficient way, you might have generate an expression tree for your expeession and then evaluate it. You can also try simple reverse polish calculators. You can google it. Look for some in-fix expression evaluation by crenshaw.

Also, a simple way to put values in the expression is by using string.format